# Is there some elegant way to manipulate my ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix named `xs`:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]])
```

Now I want to replace the zeros by the nearest previous element in the same row (Assuming that the first column must be nonzero.). 
The rough solution as following:

```
In [55]: row, col = xs.shape

In [56]: for r in xrange(row):
   ....:     for c in xrange(col):
   ....:         if xs[r, c] == 0:
   ....:             xs[r, c] = xs[r, c-1]
   ....: 

In [57]: xs
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]])
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think your solution isn't elegant? Only improvement I can think of is to start loop from second col, because you have the assumption, it will save you a few operations ;)

Comment: @jaux I would like to use some ndarray's indexing magic to do this. The performance of loop in python is not so good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) will explicitly show the replacement in one instruction:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
              [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]])


df = pd.DataFrame(a, dtype=np.float64)

df.replace(0, method='pad', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

My version, based on step-by-step rolling and masking of initial array, no additional libraries required (except numpy):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
              [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]])

for i in xrange(a.shape[1]):
    a[a == 0] = np.roll(a,i)[a == 0]
    if not (a == 0).any():             # when all of zeros
        break                          #        are filled

print a
## [[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1]
##  [2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without going crazy with complicated indexing tricks that figure out consecutive zeros, you could have a `while` loop that goes for as many iterations as consecutive zeros there are in your array:

```
zero_rows, zero_cols = np.where(xs == 0)
while zero_cols :
    xs[zero_rows, zero_cols] = xs[zero_rows, zero_cols-1]
    zero_rows, zero_cols = np.where(xs == 0)
```